# How to make std::filesystem::directory_iterator to list filenames in order

Tags: c++, filesystems, c++17

I am trying to get filenames in a directory "in order". I tried with c++ std::filesystem::directory_iterator to do so. As mentioned in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator it provides all filenames in the directory, excluding "." and ".." operator but not in order.

Kindly do help me out, Thanks in advance.

Here is the simple code i used

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <experimental/filesystem>
#include <vector>

int main 
{
  // path to cereal folder 
  std::string path_to_cereal_folder = "/home/ros2/Documents";

  for (auto& entry : std::experimental::filesystem::directory_iterator(path_to_cereal_folder) )
  {
      std::cout << entry.path() << std::endl;     
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*get filenames in a directory "in order"*" In *what* order? You can order files by whatever properties you like, but you don't say which ones.

Comment: you can get the files first and then sort with a criteria that you need.

Comment: w.r.t timestamp/filenames alphabetic order.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As the reference states out, the iterator has no order. If you want to print the files in some order, you have to use other containers.

---

### Printing in alphabetical order

Steps to take:

1. Iterate over the files and insert the filenames into the `set`
2. Iterate over the (sorted) `set` and print out the filenames.
   The entries in the set are sorted automatically.

I adapted your code and came to this solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <set>

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
using namespace std;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
int main() {
  string path_name = "/bin";

  //--- filenames are unique so we can use a set
  set<fs::path> sorted_by_name;

  for (auto &entry : fs::directory_iterator(path_name))
    sorted_by_name.insert(entry.path());

  //--- print the files sorted by filename
  for (auto &filename : sorted_by_name)
    cout << filename.c_str() << endl;
}
```

---

### Printing sorted by timestamp

Steps to take:

1. Iterate over the files and extract the timestamp
2. Insert the files in a map, with its timestamp as sorting key
3. Iterate over the (sorted) `map` and print out the filenames and the timestamp converted into something useful.

The helper function to convert the timestamp into a readable time was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61030383/how-to-convert-stdfilesystemfile-time-type-to-time-t).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <chrono>
#include <map>

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
using namespace std;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
//--- helper function convert timepoint to usable timestamp
template <typename TP>
time_t to_time_t(TP tp) {
  using namespace chrono;
  auto sctp = time_point_cast<system_clock::duration>(tp - TP::clock::now() + system_clock::now());
  return system_clock::to_time_t(sctp);
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
int main()
{
  string path_name = "/bin";
  map<time_t, fs::directory_entry> sort_by_time;

  //--- sort the files in the map by time
  for (auto &entry : fs::directory_iterator(path_name))
    if (entry.is_regular_file()) {
      auto time = to_time_t(entry.last_write_time());
      sort_by_time[time] = entry;
    }

  //--- print the files sorted by time
  for (auto const &[time, entry] : sort_by_time) {
    string timestamp = asctime(std::localtime(&time));
    timestamp.pop_back(); // remove automatic linebreak
    cout << timestamp << "\t " << entry.path().c_str() << endl;
  }
}
```

---

### Printing sorted by filesize

Steps to take:

1. Iterate over the files and extract the filesize
2. Insert the files in a map, with its filesize as sorting key
3. Iterate over the (sorted) `map` and print out the filenames and the filesize converted into something useful.

The helper function to convert the filesize into a readable information was taken from the [cpp-reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_entry/file_size).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
using namespace std;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
//--- helper function convert the filesize into something meaningful
struct HumanReadable { uintmax_t size {}; }; 
template <typename Os> Os& operator<< (Os& os, HumanReadable hr) {
    int i{};
    double mantissa = hr.size;
    for (; mantissa >= 1024.; ++i) {
        mantissa /= 1024.;
    }
    mantissa = std::ceil(mantissa * 10.) / 10.;
    os << mantissa << "BKMGTPE"[i];
    return i == 0 ? os : os << "B (" << hr.size << ')';
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
int main() {
  string path_name = "/bin";
  map<uintmax_t, fs::directory_entry> sort_by_size;

  //--- sort the files in the map by size
  for (auto &entry : fs::directory_iterator(path_name))
    if (entry.is_regular_file()) {
      auto size = entry.file_size();
      sort_by_size[size] = entry;
    }

  //--- print the files sorted by size
  for (auto const &[size, entry] : sort_by_size)
    cout << HumanReadable{size} << "\t " << entry.path().c_str() << endl;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a ready made solution, including all those gory details

Comment: How to solve the 10 before the 2 (1, 10, 2, 3..) order problem?

Comment: The strings are sorted alpha numericly. I think what you want is a lexicographic sorting. You have to provide your own class that sorts the strings. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783814/c-string-sort-like-a-human-being.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer. I think it could be made still better by using `std::multimap` instead of `std::map`, when sorting by file size or timestamp, since those attributes might not be unique per file.

Comment: @Pedro77 I looked up the problem. I think the solution is out of scope for the original question. What you want is 'natural sort'. [Here](https://github.com/scopeInfinity/NaturalSort) you can find a GitHub repo with a function that provides natural sorting. You have to tell the `set<fs::path>` from the alphabetical order to use this comparator for sorting.